# What does it mean that I can detect two different public IPs from the same workstation?

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, isp

Recently while trying to set up a new VPN configuration, I found out that I could detect two different public IPs: one by querying google (`what is my ip`) and the other by `curl`ing `ifconfig.co`. This does not happen once the VPN connection is up and running. Also, the IP results where stable, Google always returned the same IP, so did my curl command, just that the results between methods are different.

**How is this possible?** Both requests are GET HTTP in nature and both go out through the only NIC - AP - Router pathway to the ISP. We tried everything, even restarting the computer and the results remained consistent which discards any installation artifacts or memory caches. Always, after enabling the VPN, the IP results match, and after disabling it, the results differ.

As a less important follow up, I do not have experience inside an ISP and I do not know how it manages its network equipment and resources but, is it possible that I can use this information to convince the ISP that there is something wrong on their end?

My father has had problems trying to use certain software specifically when trying to log in. I suggested he use a VPN and his problems went away. At first, I suspected the ISP is at fault as his ping is all over the place but the ISP said it wasn't their issue. I then discovered this phenomenon months later when trying to help my father set up a better VPN configuration.

I asked this in Network-Engineering SE first but I was directed to this SE as I was told it seems more appropriate for this kind of inquiry.

Comment: I do not think this is related to https://superuser.com/q/50993/420061 but if it is, let me know how.

Comment: What are the first two octets of the two addresses you think are the public addresses?

Comment: I do not remember very well but If I'm not mistaken `181.48` and `181.49`

Comment: Are you sure that one of them was not `100.64` or similar? Many people confuse addresses in the `100.64.0.0/10` range with a public address.

Comment: I agree with RonMaupin - it does sound like (carrier grade) NAT